derivitation of zero sequence of a Y-Y transformer both grounded, but with out an impedance
I am not sure how to derivitate the zero sequence from this Y-Y tranformer, with both sides that are ground connected with out an impedance:)


Does this answer your question? What is the zero-sequence equivalent of a YNy0 transformer? Literally has the same picture as well. Also, what does derivitation mean? I've never seen that word before.
